# Views contextual filters for user term references

Tags: views

I have two user roles that have term reference fields tied to profiles. One has a single select (user role A) and the other a multi select (user role B), but they reference the same taxonomy.

I have a view that lists all nodes of type C submitted by various users with a single user reference to user role A. My goal is to filter this to those with a user reference who has a term reference in common with a user of role B. The view is accessed by visiting user B's profile page and displayed as a block.

My thinking was to first add a relationship to the single select taxonomy term reference for role A. Then, add a contextual filter that loads the user id from the current URL and puts all the term IDs from the multiselect into the arg, for example 3+5+9. Finally, I would do custom PHP or Taxonomy term validation to see if user role A is in this list.

Setting the argument works fine. I can dsm this and see the correct TID. For validation, custom PHP doesn't seem to work at all. No rows are returned even when I simply do a "return true;" in there. For taxonomy term, I have it set to

- Validator: Taxonomy term
- My vocab is checked
- Filter value type: term id
- Action: no results found

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or the correct way to solve this problem?

EDIT: There was a problem with htaccess which explains why return true was failing. However, I still can't quite get the contextual filter and relationship logic down.

Answer (score 1):

I can try this on a view, but I think the way to do it is to add the relationship, then add a Contextual filter of the Taxonomy Name. That works

[image]

with one Relationship to Contextual Filter, so why wouldn't it work with two.

[image]